# How to set Jenkins browser resolution to larger dimension

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set larger resolution for my tests because if the resolution is under 414 it goes to mobile page. And every time I run my tests it fails because of the resolution. I tried to set higher resolution but Jenkins didn't accept it. No matter what site I try I got the same results. I run Jenkins in combination with Selenium and Maven. This is the code I'm using in Selenium:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());

driver.get("https://www.apple.com/"); 
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
```

I also tried with `driver.manage().window().maximize();` which gives also the result of 272. This is what I get on Jenkins console output:

```
Running GitProject.gittest.AppTest
Configuring TestNG with: 
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@5f8ed237
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506106 
(8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2) on port 20546
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 16, 2017 9:21:34 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
(400, 272)
(800, 272)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.885 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: could you let me know what is the resolution of the machine (Jenkins Node) when you are running the tests. Also, please mentioned which version of wedriver and chromdriver you are using.

Comment: Chromedriver version 2.33; the resolution when I'm running the test on Eclipse is (927, 1059) but as you see on the example above Jenkins show me resolution (400, 272)

Comment: as I mentioned, I am looking for the resolution of the machine were you are running your test through Jenkins. and not eclipse.

Comment: I'm running Jenkins locally, if that answers your question. If not can you pointed me out where to look for the resolution or is it mentioned somewhere in Jenkins configuration?